# Как узнать метки поставленные на задаче?

Tags: python, redmine

Я использую библиотеку `redminelib`, у меня есть id таски. Как узнать какие метки стоят в таске?

```
output = redmine.issue.get(task_id)
print(output.tag_list)
```

не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался с проблемой, дело в том, что за теги в таске отвечает сторонний плагин `redmineup`, этот плагин не предоставляет теги через `API`. Поэтому надо обратиться к разработчикам и попросить реализовать эту функцию.